# what is the best practicies of storing images in container registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I need different images for dev,stage, and prod environments, how should I store images in dokckerhub?
should I use tags

```
 my_app:prod
 my_app:dev
 my_app:stage
```

or maybe include env name in image like this

```
 my_app_stage
 my_app_stage
 my_app_stage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags are primarily meant for versioning, as the default tag `latest` implies. If you use it for other meaning without versioning info, like tagging environment as `my_app:dev` and `my_app:prod`, there's no strict rule to prohibit that, but it could cause problem for deployment of the containers.

Imagine you have a container defined in `docker-compose.yml` that specifies `my_app:prod` as image. It's fine when you're developing locally, but when you deploy to production with Docker Compose or an orchestration service like Kubernetes, depending on policy, the controller can choose to reuse images from its local cache instead of pulling from registry every time. Now you just completed a new version of the image, and pushed it to Docker Hub feeling assured. Too bad it's still under the same name and tag, so the controller considers it's the same and uses the cached image, causing your old version to be deployed.

It could be worse than that. Not all nodes or clusters are configured the same, some will pull the latest version from the registry while some don't. Your swarm or deployment now contains a mixed set of old and new container versions, producing erratic behavior at best.

Now you know better and push your new version as `my_app/prod:v2.0` and update the config. All controllers see the new version and pull down to use for replacing and scaling containers. Everything is consistent.

A simple version number as tag may sound a bit too simple, as practically you could have many properties that you find useful to add to an image, to help with documentation or query maybe. Or you need a specific name and tag so you can push to a certain cloud provider. Luckily you don't have to sacrifice versioning to do that, as Docker allows you to apply as many tags as you like:

```
  docker build -t my_app:latest -t my_app:v2.0 -t my_app:prod -t cloud_user/app_image_id:v2.0 .
```